# How to get a namespace unaware Source in Spring-WS endpoint?

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces, spring-ws

I want to create a Spring-WS `EndPoint` because is nicely does request dispatching based on the message contents. In several handling methods, I'll have to process the message payload with an XSLT. The payload uses namespaces.

The XSL templates are already present (I have to use existing ones) and are authored without namespaces.

According to the [Spring-WS docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/#_handling_method_parameters), Spring-WS can hand me a parameter of type `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapBody` from where I can get the XSLT source and process it. However, my experiments have shown that this source is namespace aware and hence the existing XSL templates don't produce the expected result on it.

What would you suggest to make the namespace unaware XSL templates work (without having to change them)? Is it possible to configure Spring-WS in a way that it constructs the `SoapBody` object (or an `org.w3c.dom.Element` object) to be namespace unaware?

I know that it's possible to change the XSL templates to use the queries like `*[local-name()='DesiredLocalName']`, but I'd prefer not to change the XSL templates.

I made another experiment and parsed the payload by my custom code. In that custom code, I explicitly created an XML parser that ignores namespaces. Then I fed the parsed document to the XSLT. And everything worked as desired. Hence I conclude that if the source were namespace unaware everything would work as desired.

Comment: My plan for now is to first apply an XSLT that would remove all the namespaces and then apply the other templates.

Comment: Perhaps integrate Saxon 10 or 9 and use XSLT 3 or 2 and `xpath-default-namespace`.

Comment: I probably won't be able to do that because I don't control the environment and can't decide on what libraries are used.